# Rails API and original Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-api

In Rails application, ApplicationController like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
end
```

And if we want to create an API-only application, which don't require all functionality that a complete Rails application provides:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
end
```

My question is if I want to my Rails app provides both original Web app and Web API, so what is best practice to do this:
I mean, I just use:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
end
```

if that, Rails::API part has some unnessary functionality, and I don't want this.
Or I should create 2 separeted Controllers:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
end
```

and

```
class ApiController < ActionController::API
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use OOP to model your application

Let's say your website and your api share all the behaviours, then you do: `ApplicationController < ActionController::Base`. Your API controllers that extend `ApplicationController` will have access to some stuff they don't actually need... whatever.

If your website and api do not share any behaviour, then you do: `ApiController < ActionController::API`, `ApplicationController < ActionController::Base`

If they do share only some behaviours, what you might want to do is:
`ApplicationController < ActionController::Base`, `ApiController < ApplicationController`, `WebsiteController < ApplicationController`

Said that, sometimes is hard to get everything right with just single class inheritance. What you can do then is use [concerns](https://richonrails.com/articles/rails-4-code-concerns-in-active-record-models) .

Hope I made myself clear

Comment: Thanks u for your advice.